# synchronized method does not take int as its valid argument?

Tags: java, multithreading

```
public void run(){
        if(Singleton.getBuffer()<Singleton.getLimit()){
            synchronized(Singleton.getBuffer()){
                    Singleton.setBuffer(Singleton.getBuffer()+1);
                    notify();
            }
        }
```

> In this code i am having trouble getting the lock on statc volatile int buffer..
>   it says int is not a valid type's statement for a sychronized method

Comment: Why not just `synchronized(Singleton)`?

Comment: What is `Singleton.getBuffer()`? Can you show the `Singleton` class? BTW, you cannot lock a primitive type.

Comment: why not having `synchronized(this)` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work as expected...

```
    synchronized(this){
            Singleton.setBuffer(Singleton.getBuffer()+1);
            notify();
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

You cannot use primitive as an intrinsic lock. Instead, use:

```
synchronized(Singleton.class)
```

Answer (score 0):

**synchronized** statements must specify the object that provides the intrinsic lock. You cannot use primitive types to lock on synchronized statements.

Read [Intrinsic Locks and Synchronization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html) document which explains it pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

For having a lock you need an object so you can not use primitive types for synchronized block.
In your case if you want static/global lock you can use following:

```
synchronized(String.valueOf(i).intern()){
}
```